# Write File from .Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, io, apache-poi

I have some code to do a bunch of manipulations on some excel files with Apache-POI and save the resultant files into two new excel files. I wanted to compile these into a jar so that my boss could run it too, but when I do, it will not write to the output files anymore, whether or not they are present.

I am exporting it from eclipse mars, paths are relative and the code that does the file saving is

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(aggregated_path);
aggregateSheet.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
fileOut = new FileOutputStream(report_path);
report.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: The short answer is, you've changed the path to the resources you are loading, they are no longer "files" on the file system, but a bytes inside a zip file.  You need to use something like `Class#getResourceAsStream` to read them

Comment: Hmm, I must need to change something then, since the intention was to load excel files from outside the jar, grab data from them, then collate and manipulate that into two output excel files. Would I need to use the Class#getResourceAsStream to do that?

Comment: No, if you want to load external files, you don't need `Class#getResourceAsStream`